# read a json string which has a "'" (malformed?)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, coffeescript

I need to consume a service which is returning JSON. I have no influence whatsoever on that service (third party).

If I do

```
JSON.parse (data)
```

I get an

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

I know the service works because the error occurs depending on input parameters.
In other words, sometimes it definitely works! The HTTP response code is 200 so it is not some kind of access error, and it is repeatable.

Can I assume they are returning malformed JSON? 
Writing the data as a text file to disk and reading it like this:

fs = require('fs')

```
fs.readFile 'output.json', '', (err, data) ->
  if err?
    console.log err
  json = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log json
```

returns

```
undefined:1
 De L\'Embustier
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
```

which is kind of strange because it seems as if the string is correctly escaped but it's nevertheless not being read correctly.

The file is 300+k; haven't seen how to attach it.

EDIT:
Response from jsonlint.com

```
Parse error on line 1297:
...         "Address": "36 Rue De L\'Embust
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

EDIT2:
Here is the whole file then:
http://pastebin.com/ACUfvPCx

Comment: Seems like there is a syntax error on their end

Comment: That's what I was assuming myself too.

Comment: Try to validate the data: http://jsonlint.com/ and tell what it says.

Comment: Can you post the actual bad JSON? If we can see it, we might be able to make a more accurate determination.

Comment: I would need to upload a file, the whole response is 300+k

Comment: @fablife well can you post just a slice of the file around where the error is reported?

Comment: you can also try a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview-and-jsonlint-for/mfjgkleajnieiaonjglfmanlmibchpam/details)

Comment: @Guffa see response from jsonlint as EDIT

Comment: @fablife You could paste the output into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), pastebin, or Google Doc, or even put it as a file in a DropBox and share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The service is indeed returning malformed JSON.

There is no `\'` escape sequence in JSON. It's perfectly valid to escape any character in Javascript, but JSON uses a subset of the Javascript syntax and only allows escaping characters that actually could need escaping. As an apostrophe is not used as a string delimiter in JSON, it never needs escaping.

If you can't get the service fixed, you would need to request the JSON as plain text, replace the escaped apostrophes with just the apostrophe itself, then parse the text as JSON.